# Does Apple store approve my PWA(Progressive Web App)?

Tags: ios, app-store, progressive-web-apps, ios12, ads

Also, Can we achieve native advertisement on header/footer part for Progressive web app?

How to convert PWA to IPA? Can we use PWA with X-Code so that we can change in WebView/WKWebview height to incorporate advertisement?

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you can not directly publish a PWA on the App Store. However, you could use a native wrapper like Cordova to make it seem like it is a native application.

However, the idea of a PWA is that it should be findable via the web and then saved to the device from the app url. Having said that, Google *does* allow PWAs in the Play Store.

Comment: do you know if there has been any advancement on allowing the publishing of PWA's on the app store?

Comment: As far as I know, no. I also don't think that it will happen. At least not anytime soon. It does not make sense for Apple to do so.